# Gravar e imprimir dados em um ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Estou fazendo um trabalho de faculdade e preciso guardar em um arrayList o nome e a idade de 10 pessoas e depois imprimir os dados da pessoa que está na posição 7, porém quando vou imprimir retorna null. Não sei se não está guardando os dados no arrayList ou se não está conseguindo buscar para impressão.

Classe Funcionario

```
package teste;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Funcionario {

    private static Scanner s;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        s = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Pessoa> listaPessoa = new ArrayList<Pessoa>();    
        Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();

        for(int i=0; i < 10; i++){  

            System.out.println("\nDigite o nome:");
            pessoa.nome = s.next();
            System.out.println("\nDigite a idade:");
            pessoa.idade = s.nextInt();
            listaPessoa.add(new Pessoa());

        }
        System.out.println(listaPessoa.get(7));
    }

}
```

Classe Pessoa

```
package teste;

public class Pessoa {

    public String nome;
    public int idade;


    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome=nome;
    }

    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade=idade;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return nome + " " + idade;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está armazenando um objeto pessoa "vazio" e preenchendo um outro objeto. Altere para o seguinte:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Funcionario {

    private static Scanner s;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        s = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Pessoa> listaPessoa = new ArrayList<Pessoa>();    

        for(int i=0; i < 10; i++){  
            Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
            System.out.println("\nDigite o nome:");
            pessoa.nome = s.next();
            System.out.println("\nDigite a idade:");
            pessoa.idade = s.nextInt();
            listaPessoa.add(pessoa);

        }
        System.out.println(listaPessoa.get(7));
    }

}
```

Agora, a cada iteração do laço, será criada um novo objeto `Pessoa` e será adicionado ao ArrayList após ser preenchido.

---

Se não é desejado que `Pessoa` seja criada vazio(ou seja, sem nome e idade), você pode criar um construtor e obrigar que esses valores sejam informados logo na criação do objeto.

E também há uma violação no encapsulamento das propriedades da sua classe, a finalidade dos getters e setters é justamente evitar esse tipo de acesso, se você deixa os membros publicos, os getters e setters acabam não servindo para seu propósito.

Com as alterações sugeridas, sua classe `Pessoa` ficaria assim:

```
public class Pessoa {

    private String nome;
    private int idade;

    public Pessoa(String nome, int idade)
    {

        this.nome = nome;
        this.idade = idade;

    }


    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome=nome;
    }

    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade=idade;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return nome + " " + idade;
    }

}
```

E seu laço na classe `Funcionario` passa a funcionar dessa forma:

```
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++){  
    System.out.println("\nDigite o nome:");
    String nome = s.next();
    System.out.println("\nDigite a idade:");
    int idade = s.nextInt();
    listaPessoa.add(new Pessoa(nome, idade));

}
```

Comment: To aprendendo java agora e estou apanhando um pouco... Muito obrigada pela resposta simples e objetiva.  Diego. =)

Comment: @IsadoraOliv disponha :)

Answer (score 0):

Isadora, você recebe sempre nulo, pois ao adicionar a pessoa na lista, você sempre adiciona uma nova instancia de pessoa que está vazia.

```
listaPessoa.add(new Pessoa());
```

A forma correta de realizar este método seria instanciar uma nova pessoa dentro do for, dar os sets de nome e idade e adicionar essa instancia dentro da sua lista.

```
    for(int i=0; i < 10; i++){  
        Pessoa pessoaAdicionada = new Pessoa();
        System.out.println("\nDigite o nome:");
        pessoaAdicionada.nome = s.next();
        System.out.println("\nDigite a idade:");
        pessoaAdicionada.idade = s.nextInt();
        listaPessoa.add(pessoaAdicionada);
    }
```

Pode remover a linha que você instância uma nova pessoa antes do "for".

Vamos revisar o que foi feito:

Instanciamos a pessoa dentro do for nesta linha:

```
Pessoa pessoaAdicionada = new Pessoa();
```

Essa instância de pessoaAdicionada será uma nova instância em cada repetição do for, após instanciar a pessoa que será adicionada, atribuimos os valores a ela, pegando do scanner o nome e a idade.

Depois de lermos os valores de nome e idade da pessoa, pegamos o objeto pessoaAdicionada que estará com os valores de nome e idade preenchidos e adicionamos dentro de sua lista de pessoa.

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda Gabriel =)